# Choquet's theorem on a partially ordered convex set

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, convex-analysis

I have a seemingly basic question about Choquet's theory and I was hoping the community has some insights about this.

Let $X$ be a convex compact subset of a Banach space and let $E$ be the set of extreme points of $X$. By Choquet's theorem, for any $x \in X$, there exists a probability measure $\mu_x$ over $E$ such that
$$
\psi(x)=\int_E \psi(e) \mu_x(\mathrm{d} e), 
$$
for all affine function $\psi:X \to \mathbb{R}$.

Now suppose that $X$ is endowed with a partial order $\leq$. Is it true that---or, what are the conditions on $(X,\leq)$ so that---for any $x,y \in X$ with $y \leq x$, there exists probability measures $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$ over $E$ such that
$$
\psi(x)=\int_E \psi(e) \mu_x(\mathrm{d} e) \mbox{ and } \psi(y)=\int_E \psi(e) \mu_y(\mathrm{d} e)
$$
for all affine $\psi:X \to \mathbb{R}$
**and** that
$$
\mu_y \leq_{\mathrm{st}} \mu_x,
$$
where $\leq_{st}$ is the usual stochastic order over probability measures induced by the partial order $\leq$.

When $X=[0,1]$ and the order is the usual order on $\mathbb{R}$, this is trivially true. When $X$ is simplex on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the order is the componentwise dominance order, this still seems true, but I couldn't find any counter-examples nor references for a more general $X$. Is there anything known about this problem?